# How to make input type file in canvas to upload image

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I need to add button on canvas to upload image. I tried this

Try1)

```
var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");

    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(input);
```

Try2) // using createjs

```
let uploadbtn = new createjs.Container()
    stage.addChild(uploadbtn)

var rptxt = new window.createjs.Text("upload Photo", "12px Arial", "#fff");
            rptxt.x=rptxt.y=8;
            uploadbtn.addChild(rptxt)
   
uploadbtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{

         var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function(event){
      
                    var img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function(e){
                            
                            let b = new createjs.Bitmap(e.target)
                                stage.addChild(b)

                        }
                        img.src = event.target.result;
             }
})
```

Both option did not work for me.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. From the specs: `Permitted content: Transparent but with no interactive content descendants except for <a> elements, <button> elements, <input> elements whose type attribute is checkbox, radio, or button.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas

Answer (score 0):

In canvas it's not possible to create DOM elements like DIV, Buttons, UL, LI Span, P etc... so alternatively we need to create in normal html and adjust it with absolute position on top of canvas.